# Validating a form inside prettyphoto

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have a form inside a modal box using pretty photo and it shows up nicely. The thing is I need to validate it and I'm using http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation

The validation is simply not working due to the cloning pretty photo does of the div that contains my form (or so I've read). It seems that what might help me here is to use .live() but I'm not sure how?

I call the validation with:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#regform").validate();
});
```

And it's a pretty simple form with a few inputs but every time I click submit without entering any data my pretty photo just closes...

This is my form:

```
<form method="post" action="" name="registerform" id="regform">
<fieldset>
    <label for="nombre">Nombre:</label><input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" class="required" /><br />
    <label for="apellidos">Apellidos:</label><input type="text" name="apellidos" id="apellidos" class="required" /><br />
    <label for="dire">Dirección:</label><input type="text" name="dire" id="dire" /><br />
    <label for="ciudad">Ciudad:</label><input type="text" name="ciudad" id="ciudad" class="required" /><br />
    <label for="prov">Provincia:</label><input type="text" name="prov" id="prov" class="required" /><br />
    <label for="tele">Teléfono:</label><input type="text" name="tele" id="tele" /><br />
    <label for="username">Usuario:</label><input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="required" /><br />
    <label for="password">Contraseña:</label><input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="required" /><br />
    <label for="email">Email:</label><input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="required email" /><br />
    <input type="submit" name="register" id="register" class="clean-gray" value="Register" />
</fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: And how does it get into the dialog?

Comment: Were you able to solve this? I'm battling the same issue. The form is inline and pulled into the PP modal, but the validation no longer works on the form once it is moved.

Comment: I was able to solve this by using the changepicturecallback function in PP to call the validation function, and realized that PP leaves the hidden instance of the inline content (which still has the same ID - ??), so that was likely causing problems, so I targeted the form that is inside the PP window ('.pp_inline #trial-form'). presto

Comment: I'm having the same issue right now and I am trying to do `$(".pp_inline #submitNewProject").click(function()` where `submitNewProject` is the button. That alone isn't working for me...do I have to change the `changepicturecallback` method too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code as shown works fine my guess is it has something to do with the prettyphoto plugin here is a [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mcgrailm/PSzJS/) showing what we have so far is working

Comment: yeah, indeed the validate works outside the pretty photo, I went the easy way and ditched pretty photo for a different plugin which is a shame but PP over complicates things.

Comment: @Elaine Marley you may want to consider [jQuery UI's dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-form)

Comment: That looks really nice, it just needs something to check the database for an already existing user.

Comment: This is not a correct answer, not solving the issue / problem faced. -1

Answer (score 2):

This is actually not that difficult :

Take the ID of an element of PP (for example `#pp_full_res`) and use jQuery descendant selector to get the correct element. For example :

```
$("#pp_full_res #your_element).val().
```